# How to write a compareTo() method to lexicographically come strings without using the .compareTo() method

Tags: java, compareto

This is a method in a class I have created called Movie.

I changed the code to this now, so it should only return a value when it leaves the for loop, but it is still giving the wrong answer.

```
    public int compareTo(Movie other){
    String a = this.name.toLowerCase();
    String b = other.name.toLowerCase();
    int shorter = 0;
        if (a.length()>b.length())
            shorter = b.length();
        else
            shorter = a.length();
        int diff = 2;

        while (diff !=0){
            for (int i = 0; i < shorter; i++) {
            //a<b<c<d
            diff = a.charAt(i) - b.charAt(i);
                if (diff < 0)
                    diff =  1;
                else if (diff >0)
                    diff =  -1;
                else  if (diff == 0 && a.length()<b.length())
                    diff =  1;
                else if (diff == 0 && a.length()>b.length())
                    diff =  -1;
                else 
                    diff =  0;
        }
        }
        return diff;}
```

The directions say: Write a compareTo: with the following signature public int compareTo(Movie other). Returns 0 if this movie's name is lexicographically equal to other movie's name; -1 If this movie's name is less than the other movie's name lexicographically; 1 If this movie's name is greater than the other movie's name lexicographically.

Comment: What is returned if `shorter` is zero?

Comment: what if loop won't start

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh how would that happen?

Comment: @Kayaman See first comment.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "loop not starting", but I guess that would be more of a philosophical question. Does a loop start if it doesn't execute the body? Is the start of a loop at `{` or at `for`?

Comment: Also, what is point of `for` loop if `i` can never be higher than `0`? *Hint: All `if` conditions `return` immediately, so loop will never continue.*

Comment: @Kayaman Loop not starting, i.e. it never "loops", because condition is initially false. What terminology would you use for that particular circumstance?

Comment: @Andreas I don't know, I've never thought so deeply about loops. I did understand your comment, I just wasn't sure what "loop doesn't start" could possibly entail. I probably would have said "the loop isn't entered".

Comment: I changed the for loop to this, but it still does not execute properly for (int i = 0; i < shorter; i++) {
       //a<b<c<d
        diff = a.charAt(i) - b.charAt(i);
        if (diff < 0)
            diff =  1;
           else if (diff >0)
            diff =  -1;
           else  if (diff == 0 && a.length()<b.length())
            diff =  1;
           else if (diff == 0 && a.length()>b.length())
            diff =  -1;
           else 
            diff =  0;
   }
   return diff;

Comment: it is supposed to work as follows, but says that the code isn't working compareTo: with the following signature public int compareTo(Movie other). Returns 0 if this movie's name is lexicographically equal to other movie's name; -1 If this movie's name is less than the other movie's name lexicographically; 1 If this movie's name is greater than the other movie's name lexicographically.

Comment: Don't post code in comment. **Edit** the question and show what you've tried.

Comment: i'm confused by the toLowerCase() - i thought lexicographic order was case sensitive (ordering based on the character code) vs. alphabetic/numeric/collative ordering.  Are you using a specific definition of lexicographic?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is flawed.

Consider two titles: `Gone With the Wind` and `Go West!`. These share the same first two letters, so `diff` will be 0 for those two. Once we hit the third character, 'n' and ' ', is where we need to do the comparison.

To do this, we iterate until we find a letter that's different and then stop:

```
int diff;
for(int i = 0; i < shorterWord.length(); i++) {
   diff = shorterWord.charAt(i) - longerWord.charAt(i);
   if(diff != 0) {
     break;
   }
}
return diff;
```

But wait! What if all of the letters in the shorter word are in the longer word as well? Like, what if your titles are `Saw` and `Saw II` -- what then?

If `diff` is still 0 after exiting the loop, we know that either the two words are the same, or we ran into this situation, so we can add a quick check:

```
if(!shorterWord.equals(longerWord)) {
  // The words are not the same, so handle this how you will
}
```

(I didn't implement this because I'm not sure how you actually want to handle it. Probably always set `diff = 1` or `diff = -1` depending on which word is longer, would make sense.)

The reason yours isn't working is two fold. You have a structure like this:

```
diff = 2;
while(diff != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < shorter; i++) {
      // set diff
    }
}
```

The problem is that the while loop will only evaluate the `diff` condition once it exits the for-loop. This makes no sense -- diff will be set the comparison of the last letter of the shorter word only when you exit the for-loop.

Answer (score -1):

this can be further optimized for speed (which would get it similar to Java's String.compareTo()), but...
(feel free to downvote this answer 'cause it sounds like a 'homework problem' question)

```
public int compareTo(Movie other) {
    String tn = this.name;
    String on = other.name;

    // quick check - equality - safe to leave out if equals() is cheating
    // but guard against division by zero below.
    if (tn.equals(on)) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(tn.length(), on.length()); i++) {
        int tc = (int)tn.charAt(i);
        int oc = (int)on.charAt(i);
        if (tc != oc) {
            // return larger char...
            return toOne(tc - oc);
        }
    }
    // ...or return larger string
    return toOne(tn.length() - on.length());
}
// just converts any +-N to respective +-1
private int toOne(int c) {
    return c / Math.abs(c);
}
```